# JTable Record Save in Text File

Tags: java, swing

Required help in java.how to make save changes in jtable when user edit it.

my data is stored and populated form Text File.

Comment: Please show your code, this is so vague.

Comment: Do you want to update the file after the user changed (edited) a data entry in your `jtable`?

Comment: when user changes the data..im thinking a prompt user to save and replace the data in old text file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a tabel model, this is how you listen for the user's table modification. Then save the row, column, and data to your text file.

```
table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener()
{
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e)
    {
         int row = e.getFirstRow();
         int column = e.getColumn();         
         TableModel tmodel = (TableModel)e.getSource();
         Object data = tmodel.getValueAt(row,column);  //save this to your text file
    }
});
```